# calling asp.net parameterized web service method form php

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I'm trying to consume an ASP.Net web service using a php client. The asp method recieves  parameters and returns a value based on it.

This is my `client.php` code:

```
require_once 'nusoap.php'; 
$wsdl="http://localhost:49642/New_Flex_WebService/php.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
$cars = array("hi", "hello");
//$result=$client->call('TestMethod');
$result = $client->call->TestMethod($cars);
print_r ($shortened);
```

This is my `asmx` page code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(string Param1, string Param2)
{
   return Param1 + " " + Param2;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: TestMethod is raised but parameters are not passed means the parameters values are null.finally it returns null values only

Comment: Try `$cars = array("Param1" => "hi", "Param2" => "hello");`

Comment: ya its worked  " Honza Haering "  ....thanks

Comment: hey if we take two textboxes as " name1" and "name2"....how to bind these textboxes values to $cars array dynamically.

Comment: it's ok guys finally i solved this porblem, thanks to one and all...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the `Calling An ASMX Web Service From Different Languages` article, you have to provide names for the calling this way:

```
$cars = array("Param1" => "hi", "Param2" => "hello");
//$result=$client->call('TestMethod');
$result = $client->call->TestMethod($cars);
```